# Using IF statement in a VisualForce page's For(repeat) loop?

Tags: apex, visualforce, data, repeat, if

I am trying to display fields with some static text based on another field's value.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseHistory}" var="casHistory">

                    <div class="section1">
                        {!casHistory.CreatedBy.LastName}, {!casHistory.CreatedBy.FirstName}
                    </div>
                    <div class="section2" >
                        Changed {!casHistory.Field} from {!casHistory.OldValue} to {!casHistory.NewValue}
                    </div>
                    <div class="section3">
                        {!casHistory.CreatedDate}
                    </div>

            </apex:repeat>
```

Here for `section2`, I wanted to check implement something like this:

```
!IF((!casHistory.OldValue) != null),(Changed {!casHistory.Field} from {!casHistory.OldValue} to {!casHistory.NewValue}), ({!casHistory.Field})  }
```

I had this If statement in a `<apex:outputtext value="IF STATEMENT">` tag, but seems not working. I might be doing something wrong, which I am not sure.

Comment: Does it even save? You have extra exclamation points (`!`), *mostly* paired with extra curly brackets (`{}`).

Comment: Yes it did. But the displayed output has the fields(`{!casHistory.OldValue} , {!casHistory.NewValue} and others`) along with the IF statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a little bit all over the place. Here's how I would structure the format in a clean (easy to read), multi-line manner. Here I will change `casHistory` to `history` for my own sanity:

```
IF(
    /*condition*/NOT(ISNULL(history.OldValue)),
    /*value_if_true*/ 'Changed ' & history.Field &
        ' from ' & history.OldValue &
        ' to ' & history.NewValue,
    /*value_if_false*/ '???'
)
```

Now, you have to put this formula into a merge statement (`{!...}`), so it would look like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(/*condition*/..., /*value_if_true*/..., /*value_if_false*/...)}" />
```

A simpler alternative would be to just specify `condition` in a `rendered` attribute:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(OldValue))}" value="{!'Changed ' & history.Field & ' from ' & history.OldValue & ' to ' & history.newValue}" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure if I understand the above IF Statement well.
If I use a text with quotes inside a <apex:outputText> 's value, I would get errors.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. You can just change to single quotes then...or use single quotes to wrap the merge field.

Comment: Syntax error persists.

Comment: I tried the alternative solution, even I got an error which shouldn't be getting:
**Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Text**. Code:  `<apex:outputText rendered ="{!NOT(ISNULL(!casHistory.Field))}" value="{!'Changed ' & (!casHistory.Field) & 'from ' & (!casHistory.OldValue) & 'to ' (!casHistory.NewValue)}">
                            </apex:outputText>`

Comment: Quit adding an exclamation point before `casHistory.Field`.

Comment: Dude, do you think I won't be trying that before I post it here? :)
Anyways, I got this weird error: **Syntax error. Extra casHistory.NewValue**. Code: `<apex:outputText rendered ="{!NOT(ISNULL(casHistory.Field))}" value="{!'Changed ' & casHistory.Field & 'from ' & casHistory.OldValue & 'to ' casHistory.NewValue}">
                            </apex:outputText>`.

Comment: Missing concatenation operator (`&`) before the final text value mentioned in that error.